# OJ responds different results in rails 3.0.3 and 4.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rubygems

We are upgrading rails from 3.0.3 to 4.2.5. We are using OJ to searialize objects to respond mobile. After upgrading, OJ respondes different way as mentioned below.

```
addr = Address.where("id = ?", 1)
Oj.dump({'response' => addr}, mode: :compat)
```

**Rails 3.0.3 output:**
`"{"response":[{"address":{"id":1,"text":"123, city, state","zip":46703}}]}"`

**Rails 4.2.5 output:**
`"{"response":[{"id":1,"text":"123, city, state","zip":46703}]}"`

What is best way of sending response same as rails 3.0.3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working after adding the following line before serializing objects

```
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true
```

[More information](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html)